# Moment isSameOrBefore returns false

Tags: momentjs

I am using this line code:

```
if ( moment(mycheckOut, "HH:mm").isSameOrBefore( moment("14:00", "HH:mm") ) ) difference_halfdays++;
```

where doing a:

```
console.log( 'mycheckOut moment (13:00): ' + moment(mycheckOut, "HH:mm") + ' moment 14:00: ' + moment("14:00", "HH:mm") );
```

I obtain as result in console:

```
mycheckOut moment (13:00): 1683561600000 moment 14:00: 1683547200000
```

where `1683561600000` should be lower than `1683547200000` ... why it does represent an higher value for a earlier hour than 14:00?

A direction would be appreciated.
Thanks!
Cheers

Comment: Actually, `1683561600000 > 1683547200000`. The difference is 4 hours. Is there a time zone difference?

Comment: Well , 13:00 which is 1PM should be earlier than 14:00 which is 2PM.... time it's represented in 24 hours format....maybe should I have to specify time format someway in moment and not just "HH:mm"?

Comment: How did you get `mycheckOut`?

Comment: Figured out.... You made me havnig a doubt on getting the variable because in fact it was evaluated wrong.... Now I got true on isSameOrBefore function.... thanks @qrsngky !!